# GM SPORTS: A species designed for playing TENNIS

Tags: biology, creature-design, genetic-engineering, games, sports

The year is [Random number between 2100 and 3000]. I own a state-of-the-art GM laboratory with capacities to create any possible species, almost like in Spore Creature Creator. For my own amusement, I want to design species for various classic sports, such as soccer, golf and tennis.

After Golf comes Tennis.

**What build and characteristics should a species, humanoid or otherwise, have in order to be maximally suited for excelling at TENNIS?**

Take into account the following conditions:

- The rules of tennis should be followed. So the ball has to be hit by a racket on a field divided by a net, and has to be intercepted after being hit by the opponent.
- The creature should be fully biological and not need any additional implants. Clothes and equipment should not exceed what a normal human tennis player would have.

Comment: I think a basic build for any sport if you can do gm would be a sort of captain america super human thing with crazy fast reflexes. that'd cover racquetball, tennis, baseball, boxing, and basically any one v one or team v team sport.

Comment: Are you misunderstand the purpose of sport? The idea is to do something difficult with greater skill than someone else. Designing a creature to be best at it kinda nullifies the point of having the sport in the first place. Tennis? Two-dozen eyes completely circling the head in two rows to produce perfect spatial acuity, two prehensile tails to improve balance, yada yada yada... but why bother playing the sport against the "perfect" player? Why even bother watching it? Why not just program holograms to play perfect games?

Comment: OK, I just read your other question. While the details of each creature would be different, you're nevertheless asking the same question twice. Think of it this way, the first question "teaches you how to fish." We expect you to use that new skill to answer the second question yourself, posting anew question only when the knowledge your gained fails to address a specific need. In short: we're happy to help you learn how to create creatures. We're not happy to create all your creatures for you.

Comment: @JHB sport at a later time might well be like this. Advantage due to engineering. Try to explain current sport. It requires great skill *and genetic advantages*. You don't get a chess champion with only training, although you can get far. Running, weightlifting, football? You need some genetic strength to get into the top class.

Comment: @Trioxidane "sport at a later time might be like this" - and it might not. That kind of an assertion to justify the question makes the question too story-based. I can easily explain current sport - there's no genetic engineering. In fact, the use of drugs to artificially enhance the player is, officially, disqualifying. Improving the natural person through exercise and training is NOT what the OP has asked for, nor are random genetic benefits.

Comment: @JHB I think there is a misunderstanding. What I mean is that without bioengineering, you'll still have genetic advantages. I can tell you that if I had trained from birth, I would still never surpass Usain Bolt on the 100m dash, or as strong as Hafþór Björnsson (the mountain), or as good at chess as Kasparov, surpass Messi, etc. etc. I might get far, but genetics are a great deal next to training.

Comment: I VTC'd because "For my own amusement," is **not** a Worldbuilding reason.  You asked another similar question and I really do wish to make clear that we're not here to keep you from being bored.